# TensorFlow binary is optimized to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations: AVX2 FMA

Tags: python, tensorflow

This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Trying to run a program that uses the Tensorflow library and I get this error on PyCharm IDE for macOS. Why isn't just installing Tensorflow good enough? I followed the installation instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Are you sure this is an error? Does your code terminate after printing this? Also, what's the code? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: This message for sure does not terminate the script. This message is related with the performance. Just rebuild your model to make it compatible with your current architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by setting the environment variable as below.

```
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'TRUE'
```

It works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.7 (Anaconda).